# When I run apt-get update, is it supposed to have YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE?

Tags: apt

I'm getting errors like

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE/main Sources             
  404  Not Found
```

Is it actually supposed to say YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE, or is there some kind of an error that keeps it from writing my Ubuntu version?

Comment: Looks like you made a mistake while manually adding a PPA entry. Look at the technical details section of any PPA (like https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8). Notice something familiar? `YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE` should be the output of `lsb_release -sc`. Edit your question to add the output of `grep YOUR /etc/apt/sources.list* -R`.

Comment: Please provide the contents of your sources files listing the PPAs which show these errors.

Answer (score 1):

A correct line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like this:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net xenial/ main
```

or

```
deb https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
```

Note the `/` directly after the version ("xenial"), and the space after the `/`.

Comment: You don't need the `/` after the version in normal repositories (include PPAs) like in the first example. That's for [flat repositories](https://wiki.debian.org/RepositoryFormat#Flat_Repository_Format) like the second example.